# How to use logical operators inside bind formulas in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have 3 input fields in a form and want to make the third input enabled only when the first two inputs have values.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myobj.MyPanel', {
    extend:'Ext.Panel',

    viewModel: {},

    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
            {fieldLabel: 'Field 1', reference: 'field1', publishes: 'value'},
            {fieldLabel: 'Field 2', reference: 'field2', publishes: 'value'},
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Field 3', 
                bind: {
                    disabled: '{!field1.value} || {!field2.value}'
                }
            },            
        ],
    }],
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12fp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the view model, add a formula to return the value for {!field1.value} || {!field1.value}

As per the fiddle:

```
viewModel: {
    formulas: {
        something: {
            bind: {
                x: '{!field1.value}',
                y: '{!field2.value}'
            },

            get: function (data) {
                if (data.x || data.y) return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }
    }
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [
        {fieldLabel: 'Field 1', reference: 'field1', publishes: 'value'},
        {fieldLabel: 'Field 2', reference: 'field2', publishes: 'value'},
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 3', 
            bind: {
                disabled: "{something}"
            }
        },            
    ],

}]
```

Comment: Well javascript would just resolve this into '{!field1.value}' before even reaching extjs.

Comment: My bad, you're right. Hm.  Another option is you could add a change listener to fields 1 and 2, check both for values, and enable/disable accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am currently doing, I am wondering if there is a simple "bind" way of doing it.

Comment: That seems to get the job done, thanks. I will wait a bit longer maybe there is a simpler inline solution.

Comment: This formula is a very good idea.
There is a problem that in a while I try to solve in a similar case.
When using property allowBlank : false in the fields somehow bind does not work properly.
ie, after the fields have value if clear the field 1 or field 2, the third field is not disabled.
Any idea how to solve this? fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12l0

Answer (score 1):

Add a formulas configuration to your ViewModel like this:

```
formulas : {
        showSomeComponent : function (get) {
            return get('isAuthorized') && !get('isDisabled');
        }
    }
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#cfg-formulas