# Bind in button not working in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want the Zulu button to be disabled until the item inside the change function has a newVal set to it. Currently the Zulu button is enabled and this is an issue because I want it to be disabled until a certain condition, ie. item.set('textstuff', newVal); is met.

What is wrong with my code? I used this post: [ExtJS 6 - Bind disabled property to new records in a store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955317/extjs-6-bind-disabled-property-to-new-records-in-a-store) for some inspiration but still need some help.

```
title: 'Foo',
            xtype: 'Bar',
            autoSelect: true,
            labelWidth: 150,
            listeners: {
                change: function(component, newVal, OldVal) {

                    var view = this.up('uploadthings');
                    var items = view.getViewModel().getStore('things').data.items;
                    items.forEach(function(item) {
                        item.set('textstuff', newVal);
                    });
                    view.getViewModel('bindBool', true);
                }
            }
        }, {


 items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        buttons: [{
            style: 'margin-right: 30px',
            text: 'Zulu',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-upload',
            handler: 'xray',
            bind: {
                    disabled: '{bindBool}'
            }
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: `view.getViewModel().set('bindBool', true);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

or in your ViewModel.Js file you can add formulas and configure your bondbool, 
lets say you set the bindbool at the controller : `me.getViewModel().set('bindbool', true)`

in your ViewModel :

```
formulas : {
    bindbool : {
         get : function(get){
              var tempVar = get('bindbool'); //--> true because you set it to true
              return tempVar == true ? tempVar : false;  
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this you can control your viewModel outputs,
Goodluck and have fun coding Extjs

Comment: The formula part of the answer makes no sense, don't do that.